# How to count comparisons in selectionsort?

Tags: c++, c, selection-sort

How to count comparisons in `selectionsort`?

terms:
when the statements you perform to find the maximum value is 'true'
then count comparison.

The value to get the maximum value is held at the first element in the array, not at random.

I try with C
variable count position change - no work
new variable 'first' , first=sort[MAX] insert first for loop, - no work

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int sort[10000], i, n, MAX, temp, count;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       scanf("%d", &sort[i]);
    }
    for (MAX = 0; MAX < n; MAX++)
        for (i = MAX + 1; i < n; i++) {
            if (sort[MAX] > sort[i]) {
                count++;
                temp = sort[MAX];
                sort[MAX] = sort[i]; 
                sort[i] = temp;
            }
        }

    printf("%d  ", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample Input

```
10
0 7 1 6 7 7 6 6 5 4
```

Sample Output

```
17
```

**EDIT**: new code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SWAP(x, y, temp) ( (temp)=(x), (x)=(y), (y)=(temp) )

int count = 0;

void selection_sort(int list[], int n) {
    int i, j, least, temp;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        least = i;

        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (list[j] < list[least]) {
                least = j;
                count++;
            }
        }
        SWAP(list[i], list[least], temp);
    }
}

int main() {
    int list[10000], i, n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &list[i]);
    };
    selection_sort(list, n);

    printf("%d", count);
}
```

how about this? why this code didn't move too?

Comment: Erm, how is `first` initialized?

Comment: sry my miss. code is no use variable first version. but i try (for{ first=sort[MAX] for{}}

Comment: "how to count comparison selectionsort" is not a valid sentence, and the rest is not more readable. Improve the text.

Comment: @skytrack31: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't counting the right thing, this code

```
     if(sort[MAX]>sort[i])  
     {
        count++;
         temp=sort[MAX];
         sort[MAX]=sort[i]; 
         sort[i]=temp;
     }
```

counts the times that two numbers are *swapped*. But you want to count comparisons so it should be this

```
     count++;
     if(sort[MAX]>sort[i])  // this is what we are counting
     {
         temp=sort[MAX];
         sort[MAX]=sort[i]; 
         sort[i]=temp;
     }
```

Another problem is that you don't give count an initial value of zero

```
int sort[10000],i,n,MAX,temp,count;
```

should be

```
int sort[10000],i,n,MAX,temp,count = 0;
```

Comment: ok. nonetheless i change count++ position, output '45'. i think.. beacause first term..(statement = true, then count)

Comment: @skytrack31 So do you know what the correct result is? For input of size ten, 45 sounds like the right result to me.

Comment: as written at question, sample output is 17. (sample input : 10 0 7 1 6 7 7 6 6 5 4 )

Comment: Then I think your algorithm is wrong. The code you have written does 45 comparisons.

Comment: Or maybe the understanding of what you need to count is wrong.

Comment: According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) a selection sort on size 10 does 45 comparisons. So if 17 is the right answer then I think you've been asked to count something else. If I knew what it was I'd try to help.

Comment: my professor said, selection-sort comparison is just n*(n-1)/2. it is a sufficiently computable value without implementing sort algorithm. so you count comparison only the statements(To find the maximum value in A [1..k])you perform to find the maximum value is 'true'

Comment: @skytrack31 Sorry but I can't follow what your professor is saying. Do you understand it? If not then it's your professor you need to talk to. If you do understand then you need to do a better job of explaining it to me.

Comment: homework input : The first line contains the number n of elements to be sorted (1 <= n <= 10000).
The next line contains n arbitrary integers. / output : When sorting in ascending order, it outputs the number of comparisons between elements in the array.

Comment: selectionsort in homework :  1. Find the largest element of A [1..k].

2. Change the largest element to A [k]. (For each iteration, swap should happen only once.)

3. If the size of the array is n, repeat the above procedure from k = n to k = 2.

Comment: @skytrack31 It seems you aren't following your professors instructions. You aren't doing part 1 or part 2.

Answer (score 3):

> how to count comparison selectionsort?

Your definition of the term is oddly worded, but it seems to be intended to focus on the essential comparisons *of the algorithm*, as opposed to comparisons performed incidentally for other purposes, or inside library functions.  That is, in the implementation you present (whose correctness I do not evaluate), you're to count each evaluation of `sort[MAX]>first`, but not `MAX<n` or `i<n`.

You appear to be using variable `count` for that purpose, but you are counting only comparisons that evaluate to true.  My interpretation of the problem, based both on the wording presented and on my general expectations for such a problem, is that every evaluation of `sort[MAX]>first` should be counted, regardless of the result.  That would be achieved by lifting the expression `count++` out of the `if` block, but leaving it inside the inner enclosing `for` loop.

Of course, as @john observes, you do need to initialize `count` to 0 before beginning to sort.  You might luck into getting that by accident, but the initial value of a local variables without an initializer is indeterminate (at least) until a value is assigned.

> i try with c variable count position change - no work
>
> new variable 'first' , first=sort[MAX] insert first for loop, - no work

Even with the misplacement of your increment to `count`, if your sort were in fact working then you would expect to see *some* counts for most inputs.  That you don't is a good sign that your sort in fact does not work correctly.  I would suggest outputting also the the sorted results so that you can debug the details of the sort algorithm.

Comment: i modify my question. (and plus detail) can you see one more?

Comment: Agreed, @john.  Edited.

Comment: One question per question, @skytrack31.  But as a parting gift, I observe that your new code has *exactly the same problem* that this answer already describes: because of the placement of the statement that increments `count`, it counts only comparisons that evaluate to true.

Answer (score 1):

You could abstract out the comparison into a function or macro that also increments a counter.  The macro approach could be

```
#define GT(x,y,counter) (counter++, (x) > (y) ? 1 : 0)
...
if ( GT( sort[MAX], sort[i], count ) == 1 )
{
  // perform swap
}
```

whereas the function approach would be

```
int gt( int x, int y, int *counter )
{
  (*counter)++;
  if ( x > y )
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
...
if ( gt( sort[MAX], sort[i], &count ) == 1 )
{
  // perform swap
}
```

Comment: The could be simplified as `#define GT(x,y,counter) (counter++, (x) > (y))`

Answer (score 0):

You are counting the number of swaps, not the number of comparisons.

Here is a corrected without a global variable and a few extra checks:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SWAP(x, y, temp) ((temp) = (x), (x) = (y), (y) = (temp))

int selection_sort(int list[], int n) {
    int count = 0;
    int i, j, least, temp;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        least = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            count++;
            if (list[j] < list[least]) {
                least = j;
            }
        }
        SWAP(list[i], list[least], temp);
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    int list[10000], i, n, count;

    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n > 10000)
        return 1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &list[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    count = selection_sort(list, n);

    printf("%d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Not however that your algorithm will always perform the same number of comparisons for any set of `n` values: `n * (n - 1) / 2` comparisons, and since you do not test of `i != least`, it will perform `n - 1` swaps.